# Were the People of Prophet Loot Really Homosexuals?

Tags: homosexuality, prophet-lut

I've been searching through Muslim texts, looking for authentic, well-established proof that Prophet loot's townsmen were homosexuals.

So far, I couldn't find anything that clearly mentions such.  The Quran doesn't say they did homosexuality, rather Allah uses the term 'fahisha.'

And another thing is, if they were destroyed for homosexuality, than why was his wife also?

I suspect that people are basing their conclusions based on Biblical references and not Islamic.

Hence, does anyone know of any Islamic evidence clearly stating they were homosexuals?

Comment: In the biblical version of the story, the people of the town use the Hebrew root י.ד.ע to describe what they want to do to Lot's visitors. The word literally means "to know" so the sentence _could_ be translated to mean that they just wanted to get to know the visitors. That same root is used in other places in the Bible as a euphemism for sexual relations, though, so the sentence could be translated to mean that they wanted to have sex with the visitors. Traditional Jewish and Christian sources _do_ translate it that way, although their interpretations of what the sin is differ. (cont)

Comment: (cont) The Jewish view is generally that although they did want to rape the visitors, this wasn't a sexually-motivated kind of rape. It was an assertion of dominance (the same way rape is often perpetrated today).  Their sin wasn't really homosexuality as much as it was lack of hospitality and violence. The Christian interpretation is generally more along the lines of homosexuality.

Comment: See also: "[Why was prophet Lot (pbh) told not to look back?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24597/9123)"

Answer (score 3):

Well excuse me but then you should have missed these two Verses in the Quran:

> And We sent Lot as a Messenger: Remember that he said to his people,
>   "Have you become so shameless that you commit such indecent acts as no
>   one committed before you in the world? (80) *You gratify your lust with men*
>   *instead of women:* indeed you are a people who are transgressors of
>   all limits!" (81) But the only answer of his people was no other than to
>   say, "Turn out these people of your habitations for they pose to be
>   very pious." (82) At last We delivered Lot and the members of his
>   household-except his wife, who was of those who stayed ' behind (83) and
>   We rained a rain upon his people then behold what happened in the
>   end to the guilty ones! (84)
>
> [Surat al-A'raf (7) Verses 80-84
>
> ولوطا إذ قال لقومه أتأتون الفاحشة ما سبقكم بها من أحد من العالمين
>   (80) إنكم لتأتون الرجال **شهوة** من دون النساء بل أنتم قوم مسرفون (81 )
>   وما كان جواب قومه إلا أن قالوا أخرجوهم من قريتكم إنهم أناس يتطهرون (82
>   ) فأنجيناه وأهله إلا امرأته كانت من الغابرين (83)  وأمطرنا عليهم مطرا
>   فانظر كيف كان عاقبة المجرمين
>
> And We sent Lot. Remember the time when he said to his people, "Do you
>   commit indecency while you see it?(54) Do you leave women and seek men
>   for the gratification of your sexual desire? The fact is that you are
>   a people steeped in ignorance."(55) But the only reply his people gave
>   was to say, "Expel the family of Lot from your habitation: they pose
>   to be very pious." (56) At last We saved him and his family except his
>   wife about whom We had decreed that she would linger behind (57)
>
> Surat An-Naml (27:Verses 54-57)
>
> ولوطا إذ قال لقومه أتأتون الفاحشة وأنتم تبصرون (54) أئنكم لتأتون
>   الرجال **شهوة** من دون النساء بل أنتم قوم تجهلون (55) فما كان جواب قومه
>   إلا أن قالوا أخرجوا آل لوط من قريتكم إنهم أناس يتطهرون (56) فأنجيناه
>   وأهله إلا امرأته قدرناها من الغابرين

Ibn Kathir said that Lot's wife  accepted their doing and was telling them if Lot has guests so she helped them to do indeceny (fahisha) with his guests. And they denied marrying Lot's daughters instead as he offered! This is explained when we read in surat Hud (11) Verses 77 to 83

The best Tafsir is when the Quran explains itself and this is what we can see if we read a little further first Allah speaks of fahisha then he explains it!

https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9

http://www.wordreference.com/aren/%D8%B4%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A9

Comment: This doesn't answer the question,  nor does the ARABIC say what the translators are forwarding.  Again, biblical misrepresentation.

Comment: @Sayyid How do you translate those verses? quran.com translates them similarly to how this answer translates them

Comment: Even more direct are these verses - "Of all the creatures in the world, will ye approach males, (26:165) "And leave those whom Allah has created for you to be your mates? Nay, ye are a people transgressing (all limits)!" (26:166).

Comment: Alright folks, if you wish you can refer to sites like [this](http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/7/81/default.htm), for wide range of translations and then decide. @Sayyid

Comment: @sayyid http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=7&verse=81

Comment: The point is none of these clearly prove they were homosexuals.  You're adding in your own conclusions based on assumptions,  Shahwah has a variety of meanings and not necessarily pertaining to sexual intercourse or even desires.  In Islam, there's no punishment for having desires towards the same-sex.  The punishment -if any- is done once sodomy or other forms of fahisha are performed.  But the punishment isn't death anyways.  Even the Quran doesn't say they were punished for homosexuality.  This is a false conclusion.  Allah wanted to tell us they were homosexuals, he would've made it clear.

Comment: @Sayyid , does not http://quran.com/11/77-83 show that ?